# Why Java Futures don't have a `start` or `apply` function?

Tags: java, future, completable-future

For example: Scala has `apply` function to trigger or start the Future.

Is it that Java Futures represent only the result of computation? They just represent completion stage.

Comment: There is a broader *interface* in [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

Comment: Future represent specifically an asynchronous result, one computed by a separate thread.  "Start" goes on the Executor.

Comment: Because they are already started, by the method that returns them.

Comment: You might look at `CompletableFuture`'s `supplyAsync` and `runAsync`

Answer (score 2):

Because they are already started, by the method that returns them.